# Jetty maven plugin multiple webapps on different ports

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9

How can I run multiple webapps on different ports using the latest version of the jetty maven plugin?

`org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin` (version `9.2.2.v20140723` at the time of writing).

E.g.,

```
foo.war -> localhost:8080/
bar.war -> localhost:8081/
baz.war -> localhost:8082/
```

[The official documententation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-jetty-container) states this under **httpConnector**

```
name: 
   The name of the connector, which is useful for configuring contexts to 
   respond only on particular connectors.
```

Great, so I configure a `name` but how do I bind that to a `contextHandler`? This is what I have so far

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
  <configuration>
    <connectors>
      <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>8080</port>
        <name>instance_8080</name>
      </connector>
      <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>8081</port>
        <name>instance_8081</name>
      </connector>
    </connectors>
    <contextHandlers>           
      <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
        <war>a.war</war>
        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
    </contextHandler>
    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
      <war>b.war</war>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath>
    </contextHandler>
  </contextHandlers> 
</plugin>
```

This [not yet migrated wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/WebappPerConnector) suggests it can be done using the `connectorNames` property on the `WebAppContext`, but that's not available anymore.

Comment: The `<connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">` is invalid for Jetty 9.2.2 (that class doesn't exist in Jetty 9)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, good comment. The answer below contains a working sample with the only downside that it requires a `jetty.xml`.

Comment: yep, [I](http://projects.eclipse.org/content/joakim-erdfelt-committer-jetty-servlet-engine-and-http-server) am fully aware of that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/serving-webapp-from-particular-port.html

> It is also possible to use an extension to the virtual host mechanism with named to connectors to make some web applications only accessible by specific connectors. If a connector has a name "MyConnector" set using the setName method, then this can be referenced with the special virtual host name "@MyConnector".

You can then imply the context as it will contain the virtualhost:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-virtual-hosts.html#different-virtual-hosts-different-contexts

Using @ConnectorName:

> @ConnectorName
>   A connector name, which is not strictly a virtual host, but instead will only match requests that are received on connectors that have a matching name set with Connector.setName(String).

The configuration in the links above is based on a separate jetty xml configuration file. I haven't tested this but you can possibly insert this into your contextHandler (which has a setter):

```
<virtualHosts>
    <virtualHost>@instance_8080</virtualHost>
</virtualHosts>
```

That should bind with the corresponding connector.

You could also do this programmatically in Java.

Comment: It works if a `jetty.xml` is used (there's no support for `virtualHosts` in the plugin configuration yet)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on the answer of @BLuEGoD, here's the complete working configuration

Plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
    <configuration>
        <jettyXml>path/to/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The jetty.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
<Set name="connectors">
    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector">
        <Item>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg> <Ref refid="Server"/> </Arg>
                <Set name="port">8080</Set>
                <Set name="name">instance_8080</Set>
            </New>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg> <Ref refid="Server"/> </Arg>
                <Set name="port">8081</Set>
                <Set name="name">instance_8081</Set>
            </New>
        </Item>
    </Array>
</Set>

<New id="context-foo" class="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="war">foo.war</Set>
    <Set name="virtualHosts">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>@instance_8080</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</New>

<New id="context-bar" class="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="war">bar.war</Set>
    <Set name="virtualHosts">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>@instance_8081</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</New>

<Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
            <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
                <Item>
                    <Ref refid="context-foo" />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <Ref refid="context-bar" />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler" />
                </Item>
            </Array>
        </Set>
    </New>
</Set>
```

Comment: These are naked `ServerConnectors` (ie, ones without an associated `HttpConfiguration`)

Comment: @Johan Sjoberg. Thanks for your answer. I tried it. It worked for one webAppContext. I have two webAppContext having different context paths but same port. When I run, build fails as an exception is throwing saying, port is already in use. How can i config to have same port, but different contexPaths ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to do it using [jettyXml](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) parameter instead of `connector` and `contextHandlers`. Write an [xml config file](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-xml-config.html) for each war and reference them in the `jettyXml` parameter in your pom.